# How do I load an XML formatted string into an XElement

Tags: xml, .net-4.0, c#-4.0, xelement

I want to pass a varying number of parameters between two objects.  I have a method on the receiving object that accepts a single string parameter.  The sending object will be sending a string representation of an XElement.

Here is a sample string with one parameter specified:

```
<parameters><parameter Name="Code" Type="string" Value="007" /></parameters>
```

More parameters will be sent as additional `<parameter>` entries between the `<parameters></parameters>` tags.

What is the simplest way to load this string into an XElement?

And before we go down the just-send-the-XElement-to-the-receiver road, let me just say that there is COM in the middle, so I don't want to open that can of worms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XElement x = XElement.Parse(xmlstring);
```